# Tentando enviar dados para a api em React Native e php

Tags: php, react-native

Estou tentando enviar dados de cadastro do meu app em React-native para a minha api em PHP.

Segue meu código React:

```
const handleSignUp = useCallback(async (data: object) => {
try {
  await signUpValidation.validate(data, {
    abortEarly: false,
  });
  const result = await api.post('/client.php', {
    ...data,
    option: "register" 
  });
  console.log(data)
  console.log(result);

 } catch (error) {
   if (error instanceof Yup.ValidationError) {
     const validationErrors = getValidationErrors(error);
     formRef.current?.setErrors(validationErrors);
  }
  console.log(error);
 }
}, []);
```

Meu arquivo api.ts:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://localhost:8888/Projects/Web/SmartTrafficDashboard/api',
});

export default api;
```

E aqui, meu php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

if($data){
    $option = $data->option;
}else{
    $option = $_GET['option'];
}

switch ($option) {
    case 'register':
        $name = $data->clientName;
        $rg = $data->rg;
        $cpf = $data->cpf;
        $cnh = $data->cnh;
        $email = $data->email;
        $password = md5($data->password);

        $carBrand = $data->carBrand;
        $carModel = $data->carModel;
        $licensePlate = $data->licensePlate;

        $registerClient=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO client (idclient, name, rg, cpf, cnh, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $registerClient->bindValue(1, NULL);
        $registerClient->bindValue(2, $name);
        $registerClient->bindValue(3, $rg);
        $registerClient->bindValue(4, $cpf);
        $registerClient->bindValue(5, $cnh);
        $registerClient->bindValue(6, $email);
        $registerClient->bindValue(7, $password);
        $registerClient->execute();

        $idclient = $pdo->lastInsertId();

        $registerVehicle=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO clientvehicle (idclientvehicle, idclient, brand, model, licenseplate) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
        $registerVehicle->bindValue(1, NULL);
        $registerVehicle->bindValue(2, $idclient);
        $registerVehicle->bindValue(3, $carBrand);
        $registerVehicle->bindValue(4, $carModel);
        $registerVehicle->bindValue(5, $licensePlate);
        $registerVehicle->execute();

        break;

    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

E o erro que aparece no console do Metro do React é

> [Error: Network Error]

OBS: Fiz teste via postman, na api, e o cadastro funcionou.

Comment: Poem o ip fixo e tenta por pelo ip não como localhost, funcionou para mim

Answer (score 1):

Olá, se você estiver usando o emulador do Android Studio tenta trocar o **localhost** por **10.0.2.2** até onde sei o emulador do Android estúdio não entende o **localhost**

Comment: Seria interessante explicar o porquê de não entender localhost... E também, por que  10.0.2.2?

Comment: Olá amigo desculpa, não sei meio o porque, tive esse problema a um tempo, então quando vi sua pergunta lembrei que já tinha passado por isso é que era assim que funcionava.